# What is object publishing and why do we need it?

Tags: java

During one of my job interviews for Java Developer I was asked a question:

**What is object publishing and why do we need it?**

And I'm not sure I know the right answer:

*I think that object publishing is is when the object (variable) state is put to heap memory. And it's needed for objects (variables) sharing between threads.*

Am I right? Please correct me if I'm wrong. I've been searching the Java Language Specification, but found nothing that would unambiguously answer this question.

**Hint:** The question is deliberately formed in non strict and exact way - that's the catch of it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your answer was pretty close. I would define object publication as the act by one thread of making a reference to an object visible to another thread. Usually, this is connected with object creation: you need to ensure that a newly-created object is published in such a way that the other thread will see it in an initialised state.

The classic text on this (and many other thread-related matters) is [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://jcip.net/). If you don't have a copy of that, and can't be bothered to google up a pirated PDF, not that i would suggest you do that, and indeed even if you do or can, you should heed the mighty CERT Oracle Secure Coding Standard for Java's advice that you [Do not publish partially initialized objects](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/TSM03-J.+Do+not+publish+partially+initialized+objects).

Comment: Thanks. From [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://jcip.net/), chapter 3, paragraph 3.2: _Publishing an object means making it available to code outside of its current scope, such as by storing a reference to it where other code can find it, returning it from a non-private method, or passing it to a method in another class._

Comment: I'm accepting Your answer, because it pointed me to the most accurate answer to my question. Thanks again.

Comment: Okay, so it's not necessarily about one thread publishing to another, it's more general than that. It mostly gets talked about in the context of concurrency, but that's because it can be a particularly  significant event in that context.

Answer (score 2):

Publishing the Object is basically nothing but creating an instance of an Object and hence that object is available to use by the respective reference.
Normally it is referred in the sense that objects should be safely published which means that no one should be able to see that object in an inconsistent state. ie it should not be available for use till it is not completely constructed.

But in definition point of view it is nothing but instantiating an object which again means the object is published

Comment: I don't believe you consider it "published" until something outside of the current scope can access it.   JCIP - 3.2 Publication and Escape - Publishing an object means making it available to code outside of its current scope, such as by storing a reference to it where other code can find it,

Bloch, Joshua; Goetz, Brian; Peierls, Tim; Bowbeer, Joseph; Holmes, David; Lea, Doug (2006-05-09). Java Concurrency in Practice (Kindle Locations 1230-1231). Pearson Education (US). Kindle Edition.

Answer (score 0):

"Object publishing" is not an established technical term, certainly not in the Java ecosystem. It seems to be part of the name of [Zope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zope), a Python web framework.

My guess is that your interviewers either use this term within their company and are not aware of this, or the question was meant to filter out people who cannot admit that there is something they don't know and will instead make up stuff.

Comment: I know that this question is not strict and exact. But that's how many questions on that interview were formed. The point of that was to see if the candidate can figure out the context of the question given only hints on what the question might be about. This seem like this kind of a question to me, but I still can't clearly get the context on this one.

Comment: -1, because "publishing" (often "publication") *is* an established technical term in the Java world, usually used in the context of "[safe publication](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=java%20%22safe%20publication%22)", and "object publishing" is close enough that i would expect someone who knew about it to recognise it as a synonym. I think wide use of the term stems from its use in [JCIP](http://jcip.net/listings.html), but i doubt it was coined there.

Comment: In fact, the Zope article on Wikipedia is what brought me here. It claims that Zope is "the first system using the now common object publishing methodology for the Web." I found the assertion that OP is "common" on the web pretty dubious, so I started googling for the topic. This is obviously something different. Don't make the mistake of assuming two things described by the same words must be the same thing.