# Java: Allocation of new objects and cache coherency

Tags: java, multithreading, caching

In Java, suppose you have two threads T1 and T2 running simultaneously on two different processors P1 and P2.

At first, thread T2 works with some object `obj` that is allocated at (say) starting memory location 0x1000. This causes P2 to internally cache the value at that memory location. T2 then nulls out the (only) reference to the object and it is garbage collected.

Thread T1 then does

```
    Foo fooRef = new Foo();
    fooRef.x = 10;
```

and it just happens that `fooRef.x`'s location is also at 0x1000, because this instance of Foo was allocated re-using memory that was freed by T2 above.

T1 then passes the fooRef reference to thread T2 (via a queue, or some other shared memory mechanism).

Will T2 see the old stale cached value from before, or will it see the new value of 10?

Let's say there is no hardware cache coherency mechanism. Does Java itself ensure the clearing of every processors' cache when it deallocates or allocates memory for an object? (Even with a hardware cache coherency mechanism in place, the coherency propagation is not instantaneous, and T2 might still happen to read the stale value, if no other coherency measures by Java itself are taken).

Answer (score 5):

If you don't properly synchronise, then T2 could in principle see one of three things (not necessarily with equal probability):

- (a) an apparently correctly formed object, but containing incorrect data;
- (b) an object that isn't properly formed in the first place (i.e. never mind your data, the actual housekeeping metadata belonging to the object is not properly visible, potentially causing "bad things to happen");
- (c) accidentally, you "dodge the bullet" as it were and T2 sees the object as T1 left it.

If you properly synchronise (or put another way, properly *publish* the object) then T2 will see the object as T1 defined it. In this [article on the final keyword](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_final.shtml) and further articles linked to at the bottom, I discuss some of the issues and solutions. Some of this answers to this previous question on [What is object publishing and why do we need it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019695/what-is-object-publishing-and-why-do-we-need-it) may also help.

So, practically[*] all of the time, you need to properly synchronise. It is dangerous to try and guess which of the situations (a), (b) or (c) will occur if you don't properly synchronise.

[*] There are very occasional advanced techniques where synchronisation can be safely avoided if you can genuinely calculate all of the possible "paths" resulting from lack of synchronisation, such as a technique referred to as [synchronisation piggybacking](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_piggyback.shtml) where you effectively know that synchronisation will be performed 'in time' somewhere else. I recommend you don't go down this route!

Comment: I don't think this is correct. T2 can see the fully-formed object, or it can for any field see a default value or some value that was actually put there (on this actual object, not on some other object that used to live in this space). If there are any `long` or `double` fields, T2 can also see word tearing, where it sees only one word of the two that were put there by someone. But there's nothing in the JLS that seems to say that T2 can see just complete garbage that had never been put there (except from word tearing).

Comment: I think this would strictly be covered by the VM spec, not the Language spec. It's not that there's anything saying that a thread "can" publish an object in an invalid state without correct synchronisation, but more that there's nothing (as far as I'm aware-- do correct me if you're aware of anything) to say that it must take measures for this not to happen. In practice this has been a problem with some VMs (as I recall some versions of JRockit), though it could be that strictly speaking such VMs aren't behaving themselves, I guess.

Comment: But let's put it this way... I really wouldn't try and rely on/predict the precise behaviour of improperly synchronised object publication-- I'd just fix the synchronisation!

Comment: No argument on that last bit! I do think the jls puts a requirement on VMS to not publish "invalid" objects (if I understand your meaning of the term -- total junk data) -- see my answer above. If nothing else, a VM would have to ensure that the object header is kosher, or else it won't even know what kind of object it is!

Comment: From your links the concern seems to be that the compiler will re-order instructions such that the reference to newly created object will be written to memory (and used/looked at by the second thread) before its fields are initialized. In my example, though, I'm passing the reference to the second thread via a queue. How likely is it that the reordering is so large that the (quite a few) instructions needed to put the reference into a queue will be reordered to be before the instructions that initialize the reference?

Comment: Well, the thing about this type of bug is that it really depends. If you have a very recent VM and you are using a genuinely multi-core platform, it is probably more likely. But you could well write your program and find today that it works absolutely fine. But then the problem is that in a year or two's time you upgrade something and suddenly you get random crashes that you can't track down. "Will probably get away with it in practice for now" isn't the same as "Guaranteed to behave correctly now and in the future".

Comment: It isn't just theoretical, though. I have seen genuine bugs (nasty native VM errors because of the implementation of the specific VM in question) casued by improper synchronisation in a case such as this.

Answer (score 1):

You will not see "junk" left over from the first object.

Each primitive in the object will contain either its initial value (`0`, `false`, etc) or some value that had been put there at some point -- though reordering may produce weird mixes of values. Additionally, if a primitive is a two-word value (`long` or `double`), you may see only one of those words updated: this could produce a value that no thread has ever put there, but it's consistent with the above in that you are seeing the effects of a write to this object -- you're just not seeing all of that write. But you're still not seeing the effects of a write on some totally other, random object.

For reference values, you'll either see the initial value (`null`) or a correct reference to a constructed object -- though that object's values are subject to the same vague rules as above (they can be either the initial value or any other value some other thread has put in, with reorderings etc allowed).

Now, I can't actually find the exact place in the JLS where this is written. But there are several parts that strongly imply it. For instance, [JLS 17.4.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) states in an example:

> Since there is no synchronization, each read can see **either** the write of the initial value **or** the write by the other thread.

Emphasis mine, but note that it lists the values that the read can see; it doesn't say "each read can see anything, including junk bytes left over from previous objects."

Also, in 17.4.8, another example states:

> Since the reads come first in each thread, the very first action in the execution order must be a read. If that read cannot see a write that occurs later, then **it cannot see any value other than the initial value for the variable it reads.**

(Emphasis mine again). Note that this, though it's in an example and not in the "main" body, explicitly says that junk reads as you describe is not allowed.

And then, [JLS 17.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.7) is all about the non-atomicity of 64 bit primitives (the `long` and `double` values I mentioned above). Again, if there were absolutely no guarantees about the bytes you see, then it wouldn't be meaningful to note that you can see one word from one write and another word from another write. In other words, the fact that the JLS says that you can see "broken" values that arise from only one word being updated, is a strong suggestion that you *can't* see "broken" values that arise from just complete left-over junk.

Answer (score 0):

Java has no access to the underlying hardware cache, so it does not "ensure the clearing of every processsor's cache".

Most modern, real CPUs provide for cache coherency.  Some real CPUs [require a memory barrier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol) under some circumstances.  Your hypothetical CPU without a hardware mechanism will likely suffer from a stale cache under the conditions described.

Comment: Java provides memory consistency guarantees via synchronized blocks, for example. For instance, reads in a synchronized block are guaranteed to see any writes made by another thread that executed any block synchronized on the same lock previously. How would it be able to provide such guarantees if it had no way of modifying the underlying hardware cache?

Comment: @user1886387: The synchronized blocks create a memory barrier, which causes the *cache itself* to ensure consistency.  I meant to state that Java cannot directly access the cache to move things on its own between the various CPU caches.  The hypothetical CPU without a hardware mechanism to ensure consistency would have to provide a similar, user level mechanism to sync the cache.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the accesses to `fooRef` and `fooRef.x` are properly synchronized, thread `T2` will see the latest value of `fooRef.x`, i.e., 10.